# Angular2 alternative isolated scope (from angular 1)

Tags: angular

I study Angular 2.For example component needs a user argument to render information about that user:

```
<user-profile [user]="currentUser"></user-profile>
```

I want to use this component in more than one place/
how to do isolated binding in component 'user-profile'?

**Update**
For example i use component

```
@Component({
selector: 'my-hero-detail',

template: `

<div *ngIf="hero">
<h2>{{hero.name}} details!</h2>
<div><label>id: </label>{{hero.id}}</div>
<div>
  <label>name: </label>
  <input [(ngModel)]="hero.name" placeholder="name"/>
</div>
</div>
 `
 })
```

and i pass data in component

```
<my-hero-detail [hero]="selectedHero"></my-hero-detail>
```

changing hero.name makes the changes and selectHero.

how to avoid it?I want to selectHero not changed

Comment: You use `@Input` binding

Comment: Please post the code that demonstrates what you try to accomplish, what you tried and where you're stuck.

Comment: It does not give isolated Binding in component

Comment: Create a clone of `selectHero` yourself  before you bind to it. Angular2 doesn't implicitly clone. What you want only works for primitives like `number`, `string`, `boolean` by default.

Comment: Pass a copy of the hero. Or don't pass anything, and let the component create its own hero. An angular 1 directive with an isolate scope and an `=` or `<` binding would behave the same way. What would be the point of such a component if it dd not modify the hero passed as input. What should it do instead?

Comment: "Create a clone of selectHero yourself before you bind to it".Can you give an example?How to create clone object in typescript?

Comment: `const clone = new Hero(original.id, original.name)`(for example)

Answer (score 0):

Write your child component like this

```js
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';     
    import { User } from './user';
     
    @Component({
      selector: 'user-profile',
      template: `
        <h3>User Name: {{user.name}} says:</h3>
        <p>Telephone: {{user.telephone}}</p>
      `
    })
    export class UserProfile{
      @Input() user: User;
    }
```

then construct the parent and pass user into child.

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';     
    import { User } from './user';
     
    @Component({
      selector: 'user-list',
      template: `
        <user-profile *ngFor="let currentUser of users" [user]="currentUser"></user-profile>
      `
    })
    export class UserListComponent {
      heroes = User[];
    }
```